# Determine the convergence of following series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Determine the convergence of following series.
> $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ where $$  a_n =
> \begin{cases}
> \bigg( \dfrac{2+3n}{5+6n} \bigg)^n,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
> 5    & \text{if $n$ is odd}
> \end{cases}
> $$

As I think this series obviously divergence series because the when $n$ is odd $a_n=5$, so all the partial sum of odd terms divergence

But how can I prove it using Root test or Ratio test?

I used root test then I got

$L=\lim \sup |5^\frac{1}{n}|=1$ so test is inconclusive

Can anyone give some idea about this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: $a_n$ does not tend to $0$ so the series does not converge.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Is there a way to prove it by using root test or ratio test?

Comment: No test is required except what I mentioned in above comment. **Always look at $\lim a_n$ before applying any test for convergence**.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is even,$$a_n<\left(\frac{2+3n}{4+6n}\right)^n=\frac1{2^n},$$and therefore$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>5\times2^n.$$So, by the ratio test, the series diverges.

But this is a complete waste of time. Since you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, the series diverges. That's all.